open multiple tabs with chrome with the size of 100*100 px
import subprocess
import time
import platform
import os
import pyautogui
import pygetwindow as gw

# Function to open a Chrome tab with specified size
def open_chrome_tab(url, width, height, x, y):
    chrome_path = find_chrome_path()
    if chrome_path:
        subprocess.Popen([chrome_path, '--new-window', '--window-size={},{}'.format(width, height), '--app=' + url])
        # Move the window to the specified position
        chrome_window = gw.getWindowsWithTitle('Google Chrome')[-1]
        chrome_window.moveTo(x, y)
    else:
        print("Chrome executable not found.")

# Function to find the path of the Chrome executable based on the operating system
def find_chrome_path():
    system = platform.system()
    if system == 'Windows':
        paths = [
            r'C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe',
            r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'
        ]
        for path in paths:
            if os.path.exists(path):
                return path
    elif system == 'Linux':
        pass
    elif system == 'Darwin':
        pass
    return None

# URL of the website to open
website_url = "https://fextralife.com/"

# Get the screen size
screen_width, screen_height = pyautogui.size()

# Set the tab dimensions to 100x100 pixels
tab_width = 100
tab_height = 100

# Calculate the number of rows and columns for tab positions
rows = int(screen_height / tab_height)
columns = int(screen_width / tab_width)

# Open Chrome tabs with the updated dimensions and move them to different positions
opened_tabs = 0
try:
    for row in range(rows):
        for col in range(columns):
            x = col * tab_width
            y = row * tab_height
            open_chrome_tab(website_url, tab_width, tab_height, x, y)
            opened_tabs += 1
            time.sleep(3)  # Add a 3-second delay between opening each tab
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print(f"Opened {opened_tabs} Chrome tabs.")

**I'm trying to open multiple tabs with chrome with the size of 100*100 px but it keeps opening like this , like almost half the screen , i also tried changing the position of each tab opening but they keep opening at the same spot like it is shown in the picture **
https://imgur.com/a/G8yJbaX
